# Google Cloud Datastore: Storing arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm just coming from learning IndexedDB, so the concept of Google Cloud Datastore is confusing me.

How exactly do you store arrays and objects?

Consider this scenario:

```
{ category: 'football', keywords: ['foo', 'bar'] }
{ dinosaurs: { trex: { teeth: 'large' } } }
```

How exactly should I structure the database?

In IndexedDB, you have `multiEntry` which allows for all the keywords in an array to be stored as separate entries.

For the array: If I want to search by keyword, should I build a new entity with "kind" keywords and store each keyword as a separate entity? How would I link it to it's relevant category?

For the object: Should I store it as a JSON string and then stringify / decode it in the script?

Comment: storing it as a JSON string and then stringify / decoding it in the script is a simple, inexpensive way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save a list of Strings in a single property. This property can be either indexed, or unindexed.

For an object, you create an entity:

```
Entity entity = new Entity("dinosaurs");
entity.setProperty("type", "trex");
entity.setUnindexedProperty("teeth", "large");
```

This way you can indicate which properties you want to index (at extra cost), and which properties you want unindexed.

The example above is using [Java Datastore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/), but you can also use a framework like [Objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) to manage your objects and entities.

There is a reasonably good documentation on Datastore, and many [examples/tutorials](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore) available.

Comment: how would I query for a specific keyword if the list is stored as a string? For instance, I want all entries which contain the keyword "foo".

Comment: If you store it as a string, then do a `JSON.loads`, you can loop through each. `some_var = json.loads(my_JSON_str.json)`  `this_val= some_var['keywords'].get('foo')` `if this_val...`.  But, this is more expensive and inefficient.  If you want to query the datastore for items that contain 'foo', you will want that query indexed, and the properties stored as properties in the datastore.

Comment: The last sentence, does that mean something like `keywords: { foo: 'football' }`?

Comment: You use a simple FilterOperator.EQUAL in a filter: App Engine will compare the value that you are searching for with every value on a list.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin LAST question (I promise): does that mean datastore stores a list as a string, but can query it like a list with EQUAL?

Comment: No. It stores each value separately - the datastore allows the same property to have more than one value. If this property is indexed, each value is also recorded in an index for this kind/property where it can be found by a query.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTTP API, a Value can contain a list of values:

```
{properties: {keywords: {list_value: [{string_value: 'foo'}, ...]}}}
```

or an entity:

```
{
  properties: {
    dinosaurs: { 
      entity_value: {
        properties: { 
          'trex': {entity_value: {properties: {teeth: {string_value: 'large'}}}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(note that entity_value's currently cannot be indexed)

Comment: Looks like it's called "Embedded entity" https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#embedded_entitybut I don't see any example of usage in docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON and serialize/deserialize as needed:

Write into entity:

```java
     Gson g = new Gson();

      Entity entity = new Entity("dinosaurs");
      entity.setProperty("DinosaurNames", g.toJson(yourList));

      entity.build();
```

Read the entity Data:

```java
      Gson g = new Gson();

      Entity entity = datastore.get(key);
      Map<String, Value<?>> map = entity.getProperties();

      List<String> DinosaurNames = 
          gson.fromJson(
             map.get("DinosaurNames").get(), 
             new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType()
          );
```